# All UV's go black after bake AO's

Tags: baking

when I ambient ocllusion bake my UV image everything goes black. I'm a noob at blender so don't know what to do thanks.

[image]

Comment: First things first - check the directions of your normals as it looks like they may be inverted.

Comment: Reset esterior and interior normals and that did the trick cheers